# What is the phase transformation temperature anatase to rutile phase in tin dioxide(SnO2)?

Tags: physical-chemistry, materials

Usually people discuss only pressure dependent phase transformations in case of either tin dioxide or titanium dioxide. It would be nice if someone gave the phase diagram for tin dioxide.

Comment: If your institution has access, the ASM Alloy Phase Diagram Database is the place to start (asminternational.org). None of the O-Sn diagrams (all at standard pressure) indicate a phase transition.

Answer (score 1):

Anatase and rutile phases form in $\ce{TiO2},$ the presence of cationic dopants or impurities significantly affect the transformation kinetics and phase stability [[1](https://doi.org/10/ct79p8)].
It should be noted that anatase is metastable at all temperatures and pressures.

#### References

1. Hanaor, D. A. H.; Sorrell, C. C. Review of the Anatase to Rutile Phase Transformation. *J Mater Sci* **2011**, 46 (4), 855–874. https://doi.org/10/ct79p8.